# WPF Visibility animation trigger problems

Tags: wpf, animation

I have two stackpanels, where the second panel is extra information that can be slided down and shown when clicking on a button (like jQuerys slideDown effect). And afterwards be slided up, when clicking the button again.

I´ve never been fiddling with animations before, but have been doing some research. I´m still quite confused though, and cant figure out this simple problem.

When I only listen on the Visibility=Visible property, it works fine. But when I also want to slide the panel up, it behaves weird.

This is my XAML code:

```
<Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Width="600" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Heading4}">Panel 1</TextBlock>
                        <Button Width="300" Margin="30,0,0,0" Click="Button_OnClick">Click to slide other panel down</Button>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Name="StackPanelShowHide" Grid.Row="1" Width="500" Orientation="Vertical" Background="Beige" Height="70">
                        <StackPanel.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="Visibility"  Value="Visible">
                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="70" Duration="0:0:1" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="Visibility"  Value="Collapsed">
                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="70" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>   
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Style>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Heading4}">New panel</TextBlock>

                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>
```

And this is my Codebehind:

```
private void Button_OnClick(object Sender, RoutedEventArgs E) {
        if (StackPanelShowHide.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed) {
            StackPanelShowHide.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        } else {
            StackPanelShowHide.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

    }
```

Really hope you can help :)

Kind regards,
Lars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that instead of slide up animation on collapse it just instantly disappears. This is because you set Visibility to Collapsed, so there is nothing to display.

To fix this:

a) use MVVM: add some property to ViewModel and trigger on it. Modify property via ICommand.

b) Do not set Visibility, just start proper Storyboard in event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is that when the `StackPanel` has a `Visibility` value of `Collapsed`, it is removed from the UI. Therefore, even if the `Animation` were to occur, you would not see it.